"How can Boolean algebra be applied to simplify digital circuit expressions?"
Here’s the Boolean expression simplification I’m working on, and I’d appreciate any feedback on accuracy and efficiency:
Given:
(X+!Y+Z)∗(X+!Y+!Z)∗(!X+!Y+Z)∗(!X+!Y+!Z)=
X+!Y+(Z∗!Z)∗!X+!Y+(Z∗!Z)=
X+!Y+0∗!X+!Y+0=
X+!Y∗!X+!Y=
!Y
Steps I followed:
Apply Distribution: Using the rule (A+B) (A+C) = A+ BC
A= x +!y
B= z
C= !z
X+!y +(z.!z)
Simplify Terms:  Since  (z.!z) =0,  I eliminated terms involving (z.!z)
Final Simplification: Reduced the expression to X+!Y
Result: !Y
Questions:
Is this solution correct?
Are there errors in my simplification steps?
Could there be a more efficient way to reach the conclusion?

It seems the result is correct, but you're missing parentheses there. As it is, some passages are wrong, or at least ambiguous.
